# How to skip custom FieldSetMapper in spring-batch Step?

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing

I want to throw a custom exception within a `FieldSetMapper`, and ignore it in the `Step` with `skip()`:

```
@Bean
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilder.get(name).faultTolerant().skip(MyException.class).reader(..).processor(..).writer(..).build();
}
```

```
private FieldSetMapper<TravelitHotelEntity> prepareFieldMapper() {
    return new FieldSetMapper<MyEntity>() {
        @Override
        public MyEntity mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
            throw new MyException("test");
        }
    };
}
```

Result: the job terminates saying:

> Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException:
>   Parsing error at line: 2... Caused by: MyException: ...

This is because `MyException` somehow gets wrapped inside the `FlatFileParseException` and thus is not detected by the `skip()`. But I don't want to add the `FlatFileParseException` as skippable exception as there might of course be cases where I don't want to ignore it.

What can be done here?